# Efficiency concerns for re.findall on large datasets

Tags: python, performance

I am going through the algorithms course on MIT OCW. It is mentioned in a lecture that we have to be careful in using re.findall since re can be generally exponential complexity algorithm.
Is this a concern when parsing large files or datasets and is there an alternative to regular expressions for efficiently extracting patterns from data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that depends on what you want to do.

In general, use the simplest tool that is required to do the task.

`in` would, I imagine, be much more efficient that regular expressions, but doesn't allow wildcards, repeats etc. If the pattern you are looking for is all on one line, you can search on one line at a time, processing each one (and getting it out of memory) before the next line. If you are looking for the start of a string or the end, they use `mystring.startswith()` or `mystring.endswith()` - these are more efficient.

You might be able to split the data into more manageable chunks.

If you want multi-line searches, which wont be at the beginning or end, and include wildcards or repeats...  you might be stuck with regexes.